# Font Awesome Icons in material-ui Button

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, material-ui

I want to use the fontawesome icons in my material-ui Button component. But I couldn't do that. Do you know why? ( I'm using React and react-admin framework. )

```
import '../../../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

....

<Button style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#5cb85c',
                    color: 'white'
                }}
                onClick={() => this.codeGenerate()}>
                <i className="fa fa-star"></i>
            </Button>
```

Comment: Did you install the font awesome npm module?

Comment: Yeah, sure. With "npm install --save font-awesome" command. I have this module in my node-modules directory

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The error is that icon doesn't appear at the button. Only the text appears

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if you have read Font Awesome's [official guide/documentation](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/), but they recommend using `react-fontawesome`.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

It is simple as:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const element = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />

ReactDOM.render(element, document.body)
```

Taken from the link I've provided above.

I've successfully used it in my Material UI project. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: The icon is not rendering within my button. Do you have any clue what could be it? `<button class="button is-danger">Reset</button>` is the rendered html after `<button
      className="button is-danger"
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="envelope" />
      Reset
    </button>`

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan, you can't use "envelope" directly if you have not created a library. Have you?

If not, import the envelope icon as I did for faCoffee, and use that.

Comment: I have created a library, at every other place icon works

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan, hard to say anything unless you share the code.

Comment: @Faheem Yea true, but I am unable to. I was wondering if there was any general case you might have encountered.

Answer (score 9):

You can use **Icon** component from Material-UI to use icons

ex:

```
<Button
 style={{
 backgroundColor: "#5cb85c",
 color: "white"
 }}
 >
  <Icon className={classNames(classes.icon, "fa fa-plus-circle")} />
</Button>
```

here is a working example : https://codesandbox.io/s/ly4n0z2oz9

and you can use font-awesome as

```
npm install --save font-awesome

import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

as described in this thread: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2872

Comment: I tried the first one as in the link but I get an error like

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined"

Can you guess the reason of that?

Comment: How did you import icons ? did you use loadCSS ?

Comment: Yeah I used the loadCSS but in fact, I didn't understand the logic behind the icons, what is it and why do I need it or where shoul I get it from

Comment: Did you pass the classes prop using withStyles and you also need to install classNames to work this. please find it from the working example.

Comment: I did it almost as in the example but it didn't work, so I didn't use the font-awesome and used material-ui icons like as follows. Thank you for your help

Comment: import { Button, Icon } from '@material-ui/core';
import CloudDone from '@material-ui/icons/CloudDone';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
 button: {
  margin: theme.spacing.unit,
 },
 extendedIcon: {
  marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
 },
});

<CloudDone className={classes.extendedIcon} />Save the Code

Comment: I'm currently using this approach and some icons get cut off... In your sandbox try `fa fa-eye`

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using just a couple of SVG icons from Font Awesome then you don't need to add entire FA library to your project.**

> Simply download that SVG icon and open it in Google chrome, right
>   click on it to see source code. Copy the SVG path of that icon and
>   paste it in SVG Icon button like this:

```
<Tooltip title="GitHub ">
            <Button
              variant="fab"
              mini
              aria-label="GitHub"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#4078c0", color: "#FFF" }}
              onClick={() =>
                window.open("https://github.com/hiteshsahu", "_blank")
              }
              className={classes.button}
            >
              <SvgIcon>
                <svg
                  aria-hidden="true"
                  data-prefix="fab"
                  data-icon="github-alt"
                  role="img"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  viewBox="0 0 480 512"
                >
                  <path
                    fill="currentColor"
                    d="M186.1 328.7c0 20.9-10.9 55.1-36.7 55.1s-36.7-34.2-36.7-55.1 10.9-55.1 36.7-55.1 36.7 34.2 36.7 55.1zM480 278.2c0 31.9-3.2 65.7-17.5 95-37.9 76.6-142.1 74.8-216.7 74.8-75.8 0-186.2 2.7-225.6-74.8-14.6-29-20.2-63.1-20.2-95 0-41.9 13.9-81.5 41.5-113.6-5.2-15.8-7.7-32.4-7.7-48.8 0-21.5 4.9-32.3 14.6-51.8 45.3 0 74.3 9 108.8 36 29-6.9 58.8-10 88.7-10 27 0 54.2 2.9 80.4 9.2 34-26.7 63-35.2 107.8-35.2 9.8 19.5 14.6 30.3 14.6 51.8 0 16.4-2.6 32.7-7.7 48.2 27.5 32.4 39 72.3 39 114.2zm-64.3 50.5c0-43.9-26.7-82.6-73.5-82.6-18.9 0-37 3.4-56 6-14.9 2.3-29.8 3.2-45.1 3.2-15.2 0-30.1-.9-45.1-3.2-18.7-2.6-37-6-56-6-46.8 0-73.5 38.7-73.5 82.6 0 87.8 80.4 101.3 150.4 101.3h48.2c70.3 0 150.6-13.4 150.6-101.3zm-82.6-55.1c-25.8 0-36.7 34.2-36.7 55.1s10.9 55.1 36.7 55.1 36.7-34.2 36.7-55.1-10.9-55.1-36.7-55.1z"
                  />
                </svg>{" "}
              </SvgIcon>
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
```

It will work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Although this isn't needed just for this example context, it's useful to wrap the content from FontAwesomeIcon with SvgIcon so you can use it for things like input adornments in MUI.  Here's a nice type-safe way to ensure you have all the icons defined. ICON_NAME is an enum with string values.

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconName, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {
  faBars, faCampground, faSun, IconDefinition,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { SvgIcon, SvgIconProps } from '@mui/material';
import { ICON_NAME } from '../types/IconName';

const nameToIcon: { [k in ICON_NAME]: IconDefinition } = {
  [ICON_NAME.CAMPGROUND]: faCampground,
  [ICON_NAME.SUN]: faSun,
  [ICON_NAME.BARS]: faBars,
};

library.add(...Object.values(nameToIcon));

export function FaIcon({ iconName, ...rest }: SvgIconProps & { iconName: ICON_NAME }) {
  return (
    <SvgIcon {...rest}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={iconName as IconName} />
    </SvgIcon>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per instructions on: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react.

According to the Font Awesome ,they have asked to import the font-awesome-svg-core and free-solid-svg-icons to App.js file.

But it didn't seem to help me when using icon inside componenet. So, this is what I used. I imported below files to my component:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { faFileDownload } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

library.add(faFileDownload)
```

after importing above files and the code, you can add icon to a button this way,

```
<Button
color='primary'
variant="contained">

<FontAwesomeIcon icon="file-download"/>
button_text

</Button>
```

Comment: Did it work using FontawesomeIcon inside a button? I am not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: @PrivateOmega Yes, using FontawesomeIcon inside a Button worked for me. As I wanted to add the icon as a pretext.

Answer (score 0):

for font awesome brand icons ... took me time to figure it out

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fab, faGooglePlay } from '@fortawesome/free-brand-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

library.add(fab);

class FabTest extends Component{
      render(){
          return(
             <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGooglePlay}/>
                      <div>
                         <span> Get it on </span>
                          <p> PlayStore</p>
                      </div>
             </Button>
          )
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked well for me.

I loaded the CSS from Font Awesome in my root component per the MUI Readme:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
      const node = loadCSS(
        'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css',
        document.querySelector('#font-awesome-css') as HTMLElement,
      );

      return () => {
        node.parentNode?.removeChild(node);
      };
    }, []);
```

Then I added these overrides in the theme:

```js
createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiIcon: {
      root: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        fontSize: '1.25rem',
        padding: '.25rem',
      },
      fontSizeSmall: {
        fontSize: '1rem',
      },
      fontSizeLarge: {
        fontSize: '1.75rem',
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      iconSizeSmall: {
        '& > span:first-child': {
          fontSize: '1rem',
          marginBottom: '.1rem',
        },
      },
      iconSizeMedium: {
        '& > span:first-child': {
          fontSize: '1.1rem',
          marginBottom: '.1rem',
        },
      },
      iconSizeLarge: {
        '& > span:first-child': {
          fontSize: '1.2rem',
          marginBottom: '.1rem',
        },
      },
    },
    MuiIconButton: {
      root: {
        width: '2em',
        height: '2em',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

With these changes, I can simply add the FontAwesome classes to any icon and it renders as it should :D